# With vs without the C pipe() function- what's causing this behavior?

Tags: c, pipe

I wrote a simple script (taken from a tutorial) which writes data to one end of a pipe in a child process, and reads it from the other end of the pipe in the parent process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  pid_t pid;
  int mypipefd[2];
  int ret;
  char buf[20];

  ret = pipe(mypipefd);

  if (ret == -1) {
    printf("Pipe failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
    printf("Fork failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    printf("Child process.\n");
    char msg[] = "Hello there!";
    write(mypipefd[1], msg, strlen(msg) + 1); 
  } else {
    printf("Parent process.\n");
    read(mypipefd[0], buf, 15);
    printf("Buf: %s\n", buf);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This works fine and outputs the results I expect:

```
Parent process.
Child process.
Buf: Hello there!
[ project ] $
```

Then as I got more familiar with the code, I wondered why we need to use `mypipefd[2]` and `pipe()` to achieve this goal, or whether `mypipefd[1]` by itself would work.  So I tried it out with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  pid_t pid;
  int my_array[1];
  char buf[20];

  if ((pid = fork()) == -1) {
    printf("Fork failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    printf("Child process.\n");
    char msg[] = "Hello there!\n";
    write(my_array[0], msg, strlen(msg) + 1); 
  } else {
    // wait(NULL);
    printf("Parent process.\n");
    read(my_array[0], buf, 15);
    printf("Buf: %s\n", buf);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This code outputs the same text, but it hangs after it finishes printing.

```
Parent process.
Child process.
Buf: Hello there!
```

No prompt, this time.  I even tried un-commenting that call to `wait(NULL)`, on the off-chance that the root cause was a conflict between parent and child processes.  No such luck.

What's going on here?  Why am I unable to read and write to a length-of-one array in this way without the program hanging?  What exactly is the compiler stuck on?

Comment: Error messages should be printed to `stderr` (standard error), not to `stdout`.  Use `fprintf(stderr,` in place of `printf(`.

Comment: You really should be checking the return values of functions like `read()` and `write()`...

Comment: @Shawn if by checking the return values, you mean ensuring a `-1` wasn't returned due to SIGINT or some error, the above code snippets are minimal verifiable examples to demonstrate the error I'm seeing, as per StackOverflow guidelines[1].  Adding error-handling wouldn't have helped me illustrate my point.  [1]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Error checking would (hopefully; always hard to be sure with undefined behavior like using uninitialized values) indicate an issue -- with `EBADF` unless you get unlucky.

Comment: As a case in point about being unlucky, on my test system, `my_array[0]` ends up getting initialized to 0, which is the descriptor used for standard input. Apparently writing to standard input works on my system (Though I get different output from you). It might not for someone with a different OS, though. And in this case, the parent process is blocking waiting for the user to type something and hit enter so it can be read (There's more undefined behavior if you do that because you try to print a char array that's not always 0-terminated, much less at the right spot...)

Comment: That's exactly what was happening on my side- standard input was waiting for input.  That's what the lag was- when I typed in `Foo` I saw `Foo\nBuf: Foo`.  Ugh... well at least I know what was causing my process to hang!  Thanks @Shawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pipe, on computers as well as in real life, have *two* ends. And like pipes in real life, data flows from one end of the pipe (the write end) to the other (the read end).

The [`pipe`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html) function gives you those two ends by writing them to an array of two file-descriptors. The first element of the pair is read-only, and the second is write-only.

Comment: Sure, but to use a similar metaphor, why can't a length-of-one array be used as a "bucket", filling it up (writing to it) with the child process and emptying it out (reading from it) with the parent?

Comment: the array does not hold just a simple meaningless integer. this int is a file descriptor. the OS maintains a llist of file descriptor and associates them with objects (pipe in this example). you read or write using the wrong fd, and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @RichieThomas It could be, but then it wouldn't be a *pipe*... ;)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think I've over-emphasized my interest in `pipe()`.  I've edited the question title to clarify my intent.  My goal to figure out why the 2nd example (without `pipe()`) was hanging, which I think I've accomplished.  Moreover, I'm unsure what the use case of pipes really are, assuming one could get the 2nd example to work (perhaps using different system calls or data structures).  What do pipes give us that a working version of the 2nd example does not?  Or is such a version not possible?

Comment: To put it another way, if (and I know it's a big if) I can achieve the same result with a length-of-one "bucket" as I can with a length-of-two "pipe", what advantage does the pipe have?

Comment: @RichieThomas The advantage of pipes over "buckets" is that pipes exists as an IPC primitive, while buckets does not. There simply isn't a "bucket" type communication primitive in the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe() function accepts an array of *2* integer as an input argument.

```
#include <unistd.h>
int pipe(int pipefd[2]);
#define _GNU_SOURCE             /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <fcntl.h>              /* Obtain O_* constant definitions */
#include <unistd.h>
int pipe2(int pipefd[2], int flags);
```

It then generates a new pipe object, and initializes the pipefd array with file descriptors for read and write operation.

What you try to do is call read() and write() using some arbitrary, uninitialized ints (or file descriptor). Meaning the OS did not allocate a pipe object and did not provide you with file descriptors (the pipe's API) to be use with read() and write().

This (calling read() or write() with uninitialized file descriptor) will result in "undefined behavior".

> "I find that a good working definition of "undefined behaviur" is "works for me, works for you, works during development and QA, but blows up in your most important customer's face"" --- Scott Meyers

Comment: `Calling pipe() with other argument type (int array[1] in your case) results in undefined behavior,...`  But I didn't call pipe() with array[1] in the 2nd code example.  In fact, I didn't call pipe() at all in that example.  That was the point of example 2- I was trying to avoid using that function call.

Comment: sorry i missed that. so you are not creating the pipe at all! and using write and read function on uninitialzied file descriptor. this is still "undefined behavior".

Comment: Can you be more specific about how the undefined behavior causes the hanging process?  According to the script's output, we know the write / read operations are succeeding since the contents of `buf` (which originated from `mypipefd`) are logged to the screen in example 2.  So I would think that the only thing left for the process to do is terminate.

Comment: the functionality works correctly only by chance; probabaly some other side effects happen such as process TCB get corrupted which cause the OS to not be able to kill the process.

Comment: `probabaly some other side effects happen such as process TCB get corrupted which cause the OS to not be able to kill the process.`  Any thoughts on how I could test or verify this hypothesis?  My goal is to have a definitive answer to why the process is hanging, if only to post here for the benefit of other people with similar questions.

Comment: assuming you run on Linux, I would use strace. https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace

Comment: I like the quote.  I usually use "your boss, your boss's boss, and your boss's boss's boss" as the delighted audience.